# Ajax results page for outbound links - Should I make it SEO?

Tags: seo, web-development, links, content, ajax

I run a movie review site. I have two main directories:

**/movies** - AJAX only

> ```
> This page links to movie reviews, where 99% are to original content 
> on external sites and 1% is to my own reviews in the /review directory
> ```

**/reviews** - PHP

> Here I list links to my own original content, found on /reviews/{movie_id}.php

Currently I have my /movies directory AJAX driven for the searching. Building it this way has made it inaccessible for the search engines unfortunately. However, they can see my own original content in the /reviews directory.

### QUESTION

Should I redesigning my movies page not to use AJAX so that search engines can access and index it, when all it does is link to third party sites? Are outbound links important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create URI's for each AJAX load by playing with `location.hash` and then you can allow these URL's to be indexed in search engines.

Learn how to [manipulate location.hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468/898933).

## Edit

Yes, linking out is important, to authoritative sites that will aid and benefit your readers. This normally works better contextually however. It really depends on exactly what content your serving to your visitors in these AJAX loads.

Only nofollow external links if you can not vouch for, do not want to vouch for or do not want your website associated with. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Do I actually want google to see these links, because it seems similar sites using nofollow on those links anyway?

Comment: If the pages serve worthwhile information to your visitors and do not contain duplicated content that can be found at other URL's on your website then they are worth letting them get indexed. If they purely contain nothing of great value and just link out externally, then no, there wouldn't be much point in indexing them.

Comment: I extended my answer to cater more for your other options.